# Help unable to understand Google Translate API v2 for PHP?

Tags: php, oop, google-api, translate

{---------------------Final Update-----------------}
I will need the api for production soon someday, but for now I just wanted to get used to it. And I was using it for a one time deal to save time. (But I ended up using two full days...) Anyways I found gtranslate for this. So I will look at the actual api sometime in the future when it is further along. :D

Yay I found a work around.

{--------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------------}

Since my original post I've been able to get a little farther with the help of prodigitalson, and David Gillen but I'm still at a lost.

I was getting a mysterious SLL error so I read a bit online and it told me to make a cert. Anyways the result of that is I spent most of the morning in programming hell as I tried to compile from source opensll on windows which just didn't work. And so I gave up on that Idea and found a post that suggested using curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); line and that dealt with the issue, Now the error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message
'Couldn't fetch request token, http code: 400, response body: Invalid scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/translate ' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\google-api-php-client2\src\auth\apiOAuth.php:191 
Stack trace: 
#0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\google-api-php-client2\src\auth\apiOAuth.php(169):
apiOAuth->requestRequestToken('http://localhos...') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\google-api-php-client2\src\auth\apiOAuth.php(87): 
apiOAuth->obtainRequestToken('http://localhos...', '4d9609c2bc4ce') 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\google-api-php-client2\src\apiClient.php(131): 
apiOAuth->authenticate(Object(apiFileCache), Object(apiCurlIO), Array) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\lang.php(20): apiClient->authenticate() 
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\google-api-php-client2\src\auth\apiOAuth.php on line 191
```

I'm now using this code to which the commented lines to not affect the error message

```
<?php
//session_start();
//$_session['auth_token'] = 'AIzaSyAdPfnEsdsQQ6AxSn6K78LznZXHfHZIB3M';

require_once('/google-api-php-client2/src/apiClient.php');
require_once('/google-api-php-client2/src/contrib/apiTranslateService.php');

$apiClient = new apiClient();
$translate = new apiTranslateService($apiClient);

//If a oauth token was stored in the session, use that- and otherwise go through the oauth dance
if (isset($_SESSION['auth_token'])) {
$apiClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['auth_token']);
}
else {
//In a real application this would be stored in a database, not in the session
$_SESSION['auth_token'] = $apiClient->authenticate();
}

//$translate->listTranslations('Hello to the world of space', 'fr', 'text', 'en');
```

{----------------------------------ORIGINAL POST BELOW--------------------------------}

This is my first time trying to use an API of any sort and it's more frustrating than anything.

I'm trying to get the Google Translate API working on PHP. Unfortunately the documentation isn't dummy proof so I'm lost.

I've read this document up and down and side to side : http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

I've downloaded the PHP API Client shown here http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/libraries.html

And I'm trying to use this script in particular: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/apiTranslateService.php

I don't really understand how to implement OOP* so this is my downfall. The documentation states that I need to use my api key to use it but I haven't found where I need to put that in the php api client.

So far this is what I've attempted:

```
<?php
include('../google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php');
include('../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiTranslateService.php');
$a = new apiTranslateService;
$a->listTranslateions('Hello to the world of space', 'fr', 'text', 'en');
?>
```

And this is my result

```
Catchable fatal error: 
Argument 1 passed to apiTranslateService::__construct() 
must be an instance of apiClient, none given, called in     
C:\xampp\htdocs\translate\lang.php on line 7 and defined in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\apiTranslateService.php on line 38
```

*If you know of a good website link to teach me oop feel free to leave it with me.

Thank you all

Comment: The line "$a = new apiTranslateService;" should probably look something like "$a = new apiTranslateService($apiClient);" with $apiClient instantiated on a previous line, based on the error you are getting.

Comment: `$_session['auth_token']` should be `$_SESSION['auth_token']` since its a variable it IS case sensitive. Not sure if this has anything to do with your issue or not - I have never used this API :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate an api client first (the first file youre requiring)... for example:

```
$client = new apiClient();
// do your auth with the client here

$translateService = new apiTranslateService($client);
```

As far as authenticating check out: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/UsingTheLibrary note the example uses the Buzz service whereas you will be using the translate service.

Comment: Thanks that really helped me get past that issue but I'm still experiencing some problems, I updated my question.